# How to query a GitHub Organization's third party access through the GitHub API?

Tags: api, github, oauth

I'm looking for a way to get all third-party access approved for a GitHub organization using the GitHub API. I found that it's possible to get the [installed GitHub Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#list-app-installations-for-an-organization), but couldn't find a way to get the list of third-party access (OAuth apps).

Comment: Seems like the api is missing